# Eigen rowwise addition/subtraction performance

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, eigen, eigen3

During profiling of my program i found that following lines is bottleneck

```
// Some big nested loop
{
    const auto inpRow = inpMap.row(counter);
    outMap.row(adjRow) -= inpRow;
    outMap.row(colInd) += inpRow;
}
```

`outMap` and `inpMap` are `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixRX<Scalar>>` where `Eigen::MatrixRX` defined as `Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, -1, -1, Eigen::RowMajor>` i.e. row major matrix.

Is there a way to improve performance of such operations? (Except `parallel for` of course)

Comment: Looks like inpRow is a copy, is there any reason that you can’t use a reference instead?

Comment: @JamesMitchell thank you for answer! I'm not 100% sure but eigen should provide lazy evaluated proxy object (something like block). So there are should be no copy. But i'm not sure

Comment: `#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG`?

Comment: @Rzu already added :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much you can do as such expressions should already be fully vectorized. Nevertheless here are some tips:

- Make sure you enabled compiler optimizations, `-O3 -march=native`
- Then measure the time it takes and compute the FLOPS to see how far you are from the theoretical peak performance of your CPU (disable turbo-boost for that experiment)
- If you're very far away the theoretical peak, then you're very likely suffering from cache misses. You might reduce them by splitting the two assignments in chunk lower than  16kB. You might get a speed-up up to x2 from that.